# Read from console.log?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I'm new to web development, so please excuse me if my question seems a bit silly. Is it possible to read a value FROM the console in the browser as a variable in JS. an Example :
I get a "ReferenceError: incorrect is not defined" error. i want to create an if/else statement dependent on that result. Is this possible?

EDIT:

I'm using an AJAX call that sends the data and i can see the result in the console. this is my code:

```
$('#RequestBut').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    url: "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify",
                    data: {
                        privatekey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                        remoteip: document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML,
                        challenge: Recaptcha.get_challenge(),
                        response: Recaptcha.get_response()
                    }
                })

            });
```

I see the result I am looking for in the console. All I want is to retrieve it.

Comment: If you're logging it you should already have the value somewhere to store as a reference in the actual program.

Comment: In browser's console you can just create a variable with desired value

Comment: try ... catch statement around your code?

An evil approach would be to override console.log method, but I would not recommend it...

Comment: You'd benefit from a little separation of concerns (debugging / actual data storage)

Comment: what is the name of the variable you want to read? don't you have a call back method for your ajax?

Comment: callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field. Is that my callback method? Sorry I'm new at this.

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev  what do you mean?

Comment: If only I remember what it was, four years ago... Which part of my comment you're referring to, @FourCinnamon0 ?

Comment: I don't understand the negative votes. In many cases the console throws warnings or errors that belong to third party libraries. Also, it is quite difficult to debug on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can run arbitrary Javascript in the developer tools console (at least in Firefox and Chrome), but that is not the same as "reading from the console".

To enter more than one line use "shift+enter" instead of "enter" (which will run the script).

So you can write in the console:

```
try {   /* press shift+enter here */
   bla_bla  /* press shift+enter here */
} catch(e) { console.log(e) }   /* press enter here */
```

This will capture the ReferenceError exception `e`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a leak in the pipes in your house, do you put in an order for a large number of buckets to catch the water, or do you just close the main tap?

You can catch the error at the source, and you can probably catch the error with `try { } catch( e ) {};` if it's external code you are calling. You can't read what's been logged to the console, though you could probably override the logging function and catch everything that way. But that again brings you to my opening question, do you go for a broad sweeping solution or something specific to the task?

**Update**: You can't trap ajax calls like you want to, that's what the `done` and `fail` "Promise" callbacks are for ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). Something like:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify",
                data: {
                    privatekey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                    remoteip: document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML,
                    challenge: Recaptcha.get_challenge(),
                    response: Recaptcha.get_response()
                },
                done: function( data, statusString, jqXHR ) {
                     // do something with data here
                },
                fail: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                     // do something with the error here
                }
            })
```

Comment: I have tried to use try catch to solve the problem, but could not produce the result I needed.

Comment: I've updated my answer ... would have made it easier if you had said from the start you're using `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that it skips over the success and error portions. I have inserted alerts into the AJAX call at success and error, but neither one of them got triggered. Any idea what might be causing this? And I do apologize not mentioning that it is an AJAX call. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry about that ... you should use `.done()` and `.fail()` (and `.always()`, if you need it) instead. The `success` and `error` methods I mentioned earlier are long deprecated and probably don't work with cross domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to read a variable from the browsers JavaScript console. I guess you are using chrome. You get that kind of error because the variable you are referring is not accessible. It could be that you haven't declared it as a **global** variable or you have failed to declare the variable. You can declare a global variable by writing

```
<script>
var myVariable="Hello World";
</script>
```

in your html file. Or just exclude the *script* tags if you are writing javascript.
Then in the JavaScript console, you should be able to read the value of `myVariable` by simply writing `myVariable` in the console.

Comment: I actually want to read from the console to a JS variable. Say I got a string var named error. The event listens for the error to appear in the log. As soon as it appears the var error gets a string value from from the console that contains the error string. As for the browser I need this to be cross browser compatible.